# jQuery UI dialog not working on 2nd page of tablesorter pager

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, pagination, jquery-ui-dialog, tablesorter

I usually would include a lot of code with my questions but I'm not sure exactly what I should include with this!

I have a list of users in a table, I am showing only 10 users at a time using the tablesorter pager (pagination) plugin http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html

In each row there is a delete button for each user. When you click the delete button a dialog box pops up "do you want to delete this user blah blah..." http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

The problem I am having is that when I go to page 2 of the table pagination (or any other page that is not the first) the jQuery dialog box does not "fire" and you are able to delete the user without the dialog warning.

Does anyone have experience of using these 2 plugins in tandem or is there some sort of function I need to call to "refresh" the UI plugin when I move to a new page via the pagination.

To summarise: the tablesorter/pager works as expected, the jQuery UI dialog box works as expected but the jQuery UI dialog box does not load on when on a page that is not 1 on the pager.

Hope that makes sense and if there is any additional info/code that anyone needs to help me figure this one out please ask and I will add.

**EDIT**

This is the script to call the dialog.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#dialog-confirm').hide();
        $('.delete-recip').bind('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var targetUrl = $(this).attr("href");
        $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height:140,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "&{'recipientlist.DeleteUserButton'}": function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        window.location.href = targetUrl;
                    },
                    &{'recipientlist.DeleteUserCancel'}: function() {
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    }
                }
            });
    });

 });
</script>
```

Comment: Are you binding to the click even on the buttons so that you can show a dialog when one of the buttons is clicked? If so, check if this bind is still active on another page. (E.g. ``console.log(...)``)

Comment: console log is giving me nothing I'm afraid

Comment: Can you provide some sample code? How are you opening the dialog? Is it in a click event of a button? how are you binding that click event? Is the dialog a single dialog that opens and gets updated for each click, or does each click generate a new dialog with new information? Are you using event delegation to bind the click?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, I've added the script, if you need anything else just let me know

Comment: `$('.delete-recip').bind('click'` to `$(document).on('click', '.delete-recip', function(){ // copy function code here });`

Comment: Thanks @Ohgodwhy, can you add as an answer so I can accept and upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to delegate the function to a static element....paginated elements are created after the DOM, so they'll have no events bound to them.

Delegating using jQuery 1.7's `.on()` ->

```
 $(document).on('click', '.delete-recip', function(){ 
   // copy function code here
 });
```

Comment: Much appreciated, been trying to fix that for a while.